# delay in alarmmanager .. when two alarms exists simultaneously

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have scheduled multiple alarm managers to send intents at different times.
I took care to pass unique ID, context and extras to both the pending intents.
 below func handles the alarm calls.
.

```
public void handle(int duration, int id){
Intent intent = new Intent("package.SET"); 
intent.putExtra ("package.id", Id); 
 AlarmManager amg = (AlarmManager)Context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pis = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Context,Id, intent, FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
amg.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + time, pis); }
```

there are 2 functions calling the alarm

```
public void callalarm(int time){
 handle(time, UNIQUE_ID1);}
```

and

```
public void callalarm2(int time){
  handle(time, UNIQUE_ID2);}
```

I took care that unique ID1 and Unique_ID2 are different.
The broadcast receiver handles the alarm and executes another code.
Is there a possibility that Callalarm1 and callalarm2 interfere with eachother .

> ***I have registered the receiver using registerReceiver function and not in android manifest file***.

```
       IntentFilter ARFilter = new IntentFilter();
    ARFilter.addAction("package.SET");
     context.registerReceiver(AR, ARFilter);
```

In the AR that extends broadcast receiver, i use the id to define the action.

```
public BroadcastReceiver AR= new BroadcastReceiver()
 { public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
  {    // i do some stuff here which is confidential
        }}
```

The problem is that, I get a delay in the alarms. Is there a reason why there is a delay ?

Comment: Oh USers of Stakc Overfloe  Why u no giving me solution ?

Answer (score 1):

As of What I know, The Alarm MAnager cannot fire at right times when the task burden on the processor is heavy.

In other words, the broadcast receiver does not receive intent on time since the alarm manager adds the broadcast to the queue which is sent with some delay..

Precise information is helpful.